New manjaro install, but wrong password even during reset
I just installed Manjaro, I have used other distros like Ubuntu and Mint before.
After installing it I wanted to switch to root user, so I ran sudo su, went to give my password and it keeps saying it's wrong. I tried to reset my password. Trying to reset my password doesn't let me because the new password I'm trying to pick is the existing password, so what is the issue??

I fixed it by opening a new terminal.
